# Kivy execution error

Tags: python, kivy

Iam trying to run a simple sample code of Hello World which is as follows:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

and i have saved this as hello.py which then i run by using kivy-1.8.0 which in turn gives me an error message titled Kivy Fatal Error and the rest of the description is in Chinese,Japanese or Korean language.

Is there a problem of graphics card? or 
Is there any other way to a Kivy application

please help.

Answer (score 2):

Please post the full terminal output from when the app is run.

I don't remember what the funny character message means (it's nonsense, not real text), but I think it indicates a too-low opengl version. The appearance of the garbled message is itself a bug that I think is fixed in kivy master.

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues with kivy (and python):

- Indentation issues: make doubly sure that your indents are consistent: they should all be the same. If you are using a tab, make sure it is a tab everywhere. If you are using multiple spaces make sure they are the same number everywhere.
- A more kivy specific issue: try to comment out line 2 (`kivy.require('1.8.0')`). You may not have the correct version of kivy installed. Alternatively, decrease that number (1.0.6 should be more than enough for what you are doing in this simple application).

I don't know what the issue could be with the language you get the message in. Perhaps you installed some weird distribution, or selected some language pack that it is defaulting to.